# 404s or Redirects?

Tags: redirect, shopify, sitemap

This is a pretty basic questions, but I'm not sure what's the best way to proceed and I feel caught between a rock and a hard place. I copied about 600 product listings into a shopify store from Etsy. Recently, I changed the URL handles (the URLs) in Shopify to match the revised product titles, which led to a bunch of 404s, so I uploaded the redirects (about 300 of them out of 600 products). Recently, I had someone do some work on my site who removed all the redirects stating it wasn't good practice. He also uploaded a new sitemap to Google. While I appreciate that the redirects may slow down my (already slow) site, I am getting a lot of 404s, mainly from Pinterest. I don't know if it's better to live with 404s or a lot of redirects. Any ideas, or suggestions, would be greately appreciated. Thanks!

I had uploaded the URLs, but they were deleted. I determined the 404s are generated through Pinterest.

Comment: Redirects are fast. Don't worry about their speed. Your web person has likely determined that redirects would hurt SEO/google rankings in your case. Nonetheless, if you are seeing a large amount of 404s that could otherwise become a conversion, then that should be something you talk about with your developer.

Comment: Done right, redirects do not hurt SEO, and they are not slow. Just make sure to use a [301 Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) to let your users and search engines know that the page now has a new URL.